# Why can't the type or namespace be found on IIS 7 server when it works fine on the local machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, iis-7, namespaces

I am using DynamicPDF creator, Visual Studio 2010, and IIS 7.

On my local machine, the line "using ceTe.DynamicPDF;" and subsequent lines work fine, but 
when I try to load the page on my server, I get the following error:

"Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ceTe' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have added the .dll file as a reference, and intellisense even works.

I am wondering if it is a problem with assemblies.  Any ideas about what I should do to get this working on my server?

Comment: Did you install DynamicPDF in your server? May be some of its dependent dll lost? watch it in [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Look if there's a missing reference from DynamicPDF dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you lost some of dlls, you can check dll which contains `ceTe. ...` by [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Hi Saeed Amiri - I know more than a month has gone by, but I am returning to this project.  I downloaded the dependency walker program, and it is saying that IESHIMS.DLL and WER.DLL are missing.  I have been reading up on this, and it seems as though they may not be necessary.  I was just wondering if, by chance, you know anything about this.  Thanks again for your help.  Cheers.

Comment: (Also, you asked previously if I installed DynamicPDF on my server.  I did.)

Comment: you should place the required dlls in GAC (search it: global assembly cache).